# Swap! value doesn't resolve

Tags: xml, clojure, lazy-evaluation

While parsing an xml file, I normalize values and save them via swap! into an atom. Additional I build a tree to reflect the original structure.

When I call the function, it returns only a part of the data, but not the normalized values. When I deref the atom, the data is completely written.

Here the parts of the code, which seems to be critical to that behaviour.

```
(defn normalize-values
  "Save the dataset to the atom and returns the reference"
  [tour-id key value]
  (swap! db assoc-in [tour-id (query-key key :name) value] {:title value})
  {key [(query-key key) value]})


(defn extract-tags
  "Differs between unique and normalizable values"
  [node tour-id]
  (let [data (zip/xml-zip node)
        key (:tag node)
        value (zx/xml1-> data key zx/text)
        res (if (some #{key} [:sound :map :video :creator])
              (normalize-values tour-id key value)
              {key value})]
    res))

(defn panorama->map
  "Creates a panorama map from the xml data"
  [node tour-id]
  (let [xml-node (zip/node node)
        tag-values (into {} (map #(extract-tags % tour-id) (:content xml-node)))]
    (merge tag-values
           {:id     (get-file-id (:file tag-values))
            :hidden (read-string (get-in xml-node [:attrs :hidden]))})))


(defn menu->map
  "Loops over the xml tree and builds the structure"
  [tour-id menu]
  (for [entry menu]
    (let [children (childs-of-child entry)]
      (if (not-empty children)
        (let [{:keys [id] :as category-map} (category->map entry)]
          (swap! db assoc-in [tour-id (query-key :categorie :id) id] category-map)
          {:loc      [:categories/by-id id]
           :children (menu->map tour-id children)})

        (let [{:keys [id] :as panorama-map} (panorama->map entry tour-id)]
          (swap! db assoc-in [tour-id (query-key :pano :id) id] panorama-map)

          {:loc [:panos/by-id id]})))))

(defn parse-menu
  "Starting function which resets the db and saves all data to the atom "
  [path id]
  (swap! db dissoc id)
  (logging/debug "Parse Menu: " path)

  (let [xml (xml->map path)
        menu-data (menu->map id (:content xml))]

    (swap! db assoc-in [id :title] (tour-title xml))
    (swap! db assoc-in [id :tree] menu-data)

    (get @db id)))
```

How can I realize, that the atom is resolved correctly?

Comment: Can you be more clear about where exactly things are going wrong, and what you've seen while debugging? Also, can you post the source of `xml->map`?

Comment: Thank you, the hint to the vec brought the solution. I forgot, that for is lazy too.

Answer (score 1):

`for` is lazy, and will not perform the side effects you have snuck into its body until you realize the elements of the sequence it produces. Your description "When I deref the atom, the data is completely written." is unclear, but I suspect you mean you deref it in the repl, causing its value to be printed, which forces the lazy seqs embedded in it, which causes their side effects to run.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alan Thompson commented, where the source of the error the lazy evaluation. After prepending a `(vec)` before the `(for)` loops, the problem has gone.

```
(defn menu->map
  "Loops over the xml tree and builds the structure"
  [tour-id menu]

  (vec    ;;forcing the evaluation of the loop

   (for [entry menu]
     (let [children (childs-of-child entry)]
       (if (not-empty children)
         (let [{:keys [id] :as category-map} (category->map entry)]
           (swap! db assoc-in [tour-id (query-key :categorie :id) id] category-map)
           {:loc      [:categories/by-id id]
            :children (menu->map tour-id children)})

         (let [{:keys [id] :as panorama-map} (panorama->map entry tour-id)]
           (swap! db assoc-in [tour-id (query-key :pano :id) id] panorama-map)

           {:loc [:panos/by-id id]}))))))
```